# How to load binary module

Tags: module, erlang

Next compiles well

```
-module(cipher_id).
-export([a1/1]).

a1(I) ->
    binary:encode_unsigned(I).
```

But then i try to call cipher_id:a1(I) it crashes with

> ** exception error: undefined function binary:encode_unsigned/1

The same happened if try to call function from binary module in erl shell. m() outputs lists in which no binary module present.

Comment: What version of Erlang are you using? How did you install it?

Comment: @Roberto Aloi: R13B03, its not me who installed it. If you think what problem in not full or wrong installation, then i will reinstall it with newer Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Erlang documentation of the [binary module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/binary.html):

> The module is implemented according to the EEP (Erlang Enhancement Proposal) 31.

From [the proposal page](http://www.erlang.org/eeps/eep-0031.html):

> Status:         Final/R14A Proposal is implemented in OTP release R14A

You're using R13B03. My feeling is that you need to upgrade to a newer Erlang installation. Binaries for Ubuntu are available at:

http://www.erlang-solutions.com/section/132/erlang-otp-packages